# What's the proper way to store external/unauthenticated users in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, activerecord

My site enables communication between both registered and non-registered users.  I'm trying to determine the best practice for storing non-registered users in the database.  My initial schema was as follows:

```
Users
------------
user_id
device_id *Unique* (this is for mobile app users)
email *Unique*
phone *Unique*
first_name
last_name
image_url
date_joined

UserNames  (Users have custom names for each group potentially)
-------------
name_id
user_id
group_id
first_name
last_name
```

Further details of how the app works:

- Users register and create groups/lists which include both registered and non-registered users
- Messages are then sent to members of the groups/lists
- Note: registered users can add non-registered users to lists without their explicit approval.

I chose the design listed above because emails, phone numbers, and device IDs would be unique.  However users may have different names/nick names for each of the users, hence the UserNames table.  However it's not clear to me whether or not storing non-registered users should be stored in the Users table given that they aren't technically registered users of the site.

Should I be storing the non-registered/external users in a separate table?  Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you segregate unregistered user into their own table is a design decision probably only you can answer.  It would probably depend on how these different user types are used throughout your application.  It could be something as simple as having a tinyint field with 0 or 1 values to indicate a user is registered.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with storing "non-users" in the "users" table?  It's more of a semantical discussion I guess.  Something just feels wrong about storing a non-user as a "User".

Comment: +1 on the use of a tinyint field. It sounds like "unregistered" users are still part of your app design (eg you want messages sent to them) which means you'll want to maintain a record.

So then the question is different table or not. If the characteristics are very similar to registered users, keep it in the same table.

Comment: To me it depends on your application and expected size of the table.  If you are not really going to be persisting any date about non-registeres users, then I would probably not have them in the database at all (and just have them handled in the code as anonymous users), but if you are doing things like having registered user invite unregistered users to where you need to persist the unregistered users' information, then there is nothing wrong at all with having them in the database.

Comment: To me I try to look at it in real-world terms.  Is the registered user going to have additional data properties that the un-registered user doesn't have (or vice versa)? If so it may make sense to have them in different tables with different structures.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Sounds like the primary issue to focus on is whether or not there will be an excessive # of non-registered users with empty date_joined fields.  Not sure how much of an impact that will ultimately have.  What's the downside of having a bunch of empty date fields?  I could theoretically store that in a different table and instead add a tinyint field which is "is_external" or whatever.

Comment: @NickONeill If the users were exactly the same with the exception of having an is_external or is_registered type fo field and you are not expecting this table to grow into the tens of millions of users, then I probably wouldn't be that worried about the volume of users in the table. As long as your table is properly indexed for the lookups you will be performing, and assuming you have a properly sized server to store the indexes in memory, dealing with a relatively large user table should not be a problem.